# Typedef signature vs signature alias

Tags: c++, c++11, alias, typedef

Why can I compile the following:

```
typedef void OnSuccessSignature(PathFinderType::EdgePath);
```

but not this?:

```
using OnSuccessSignature = void(PathFinderType::EdgePath);
```

The second line gives a `C2061: syntax error : identifier 'EdgePath'`

In case it makes a difference, the relevant part of the class is defined as

```
class MapManager : public Service<MapManager>
{
public:
    //  Aliases.
    using PathFinderType = AStar<Map::MapNodeType, WeightedEuclideanDistance<Map::MapNodeType>>;
    using OnSuccessSignature = void(PathFinderType::EdgePath);

    //  ...
}
```

and `AStar`

```
template <typename TNode, typename THeuristic = EuclideanDistanceSqrd<TNode>>
class AStar : Detail::AStarHeap<TNode>
{
public:
    //  Aliases.
    using EdgePath = list<typename TNode::EdgeType*>;

    //   ...
}
```

I've included the second header in the first.

Comment: I'm looking at the rules for `typedef` and I can't read this :(

Comment: Seriously? I'll try a clean and rebuild.

Comment: [VS2013 doesn't like it](http://rextester.com/RFUZ87359), [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e1fdbdf4b36c511) and [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/242e27f363843e8e) do. My money is on MSVC bug.

Comment: The compile error comes up whenever I try a non-POD type in the alias.

Comment: @Casey: That link is so much more awesome than the official one that claims everything compmiles: http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/vwQ7

Comment: @MooingDuck IIRC, rextester.com runs VS2013 RTM, not the CTP.

Comment: [`typedef` instead of `using` seems to workaround the issue](http://rextester.com/GKE14081).

Comment: It does. But for consistency's sake, you know... Ah well, to hell with consistency.